# Why would we expect integration by parts to generate an asymptotic approximation to the integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, approximation

I'm doing a perturbation methods course where we have shown that often (but not always - e.g. if dominant contribution is not at an end point of the integral, or if boundary term diverges etc), doing integration by parts succesively will generate an asymptotic approximation to the integral.

Whereas for Laplace's method and the method of stationary phase (etc) I have a 'mental picture' of why I would expect these methods to generate an asymptotic approximation, I have nothing for this integration by parts method.

My question is, is integration by parts purely an 'almost random method that often works' to generate an asymptotic approximation, or is there some mental picture you can give me for why we *expect* it to sometimes do this?

Comment: Try reading this: http://pordlabs.ucsd.edu/wryoung/SIO203C2017/PartB_Asymptotics&Integrals.pdf

Comment: if we look at $\int_{x}^{\infty}dt e^{-t}/t$ as an example, for large $x$ we have that under ibp that one term gets smaller with every iteration (derivatives of $1/t$) and one term stays constant in magnitude (integrals of $e^{-t}$). that way we get a series of asymptotically decreasing terms if we repeat ibp. 
I don't know if this holds always true (it feels like), but thats my mental picture of this method: We can split the integrand into pieces where one goes much faster to zero then the other goes to infinity under application of ibp.

Comment: @asgeige Amazing, this is precisely the sort of 'intuitve explanation' I was looking for. It also tally's up with the cases where we were taught this method doesn't work.

Comment: As integral at expansion point must be finite, we see this method breaks if: 1) If the dominant contribution is not at a limit point (therefore the '$-\int vdu$' term will always invetiably be big), 2) if the series of boundary terms decrease but 'too fast' (e.g. by $\frac{1}{x^n}$ [for large $x$] for an exact result $\propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ so the '$-\int vdu$' term again must inevitably be large, 3) if the integrand diverges at a limit point (therefore the '$-\int v du$' term must be an infinite (large) correction)

Comment: you are welcome. Yeah at it boils down to the requirement that $|v u| >> |\int v du| $ in some sense. Also, if the boundary contributions vanish (so above requriement is not fulfilled) we have to look into "the middle" of our integration interval or even into the whole complex plane and then we are back at Laplace/Steepest descent..... (which handles problems with dominant boundary contributions as a special case)